# Is there a way to tag a previous layer in a docker image or revert a commit?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Let's say there is a docker image, someone makes changes to it and then pushes it up to a docker repository. I then pull down the image. Is there a way to then take that image and run a container from a previous layer? Run the version before the changes were made.

If I run docker history it will look something like this:

```
docker history imagename:tag
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
3e23a5875458        8 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8            0 B
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c dpkg-reconfigure locales &&    loc   1.245 MB
<missing>           8 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install    338.3 MB
<missing>           6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD jessie.tar.xz in /        121 MB
<missing>           6 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER ssss <ad   0 B
<missing>           9 months ago                                                        0 B
```

It seems as if I could run an earlier version if I figure out a way to somehow tag or identify previous layers of the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can, by tagging build layers of the image if you have access to them. As described [here](https://gist.github.com/dasgoll/476ecc7a057ac885f0be).

In your case what could be happening is that from version v1.10.0 forward they've changed the way that the [docker engine handles content addressability](https://github.com/docker/docker/wiki/Engine-v1.10.0-content-addressability-migration). This is being heavily discussed [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20316).

What it means is that you won't have access to the build layers unless you built this image in the current machine or exported and loaded by combining:

```
docker save imagename build-layer1 build-layer2 build-layer3 > image-caching.tar
docker load -i image-caching.tar
```

A user has posted a handy way to save that cache in the discussion I've mentioned previously:

```
docker save imagename $(sudo docker history -q imagename | tail -n +2 | grep -v \<missing\> | tr '\n' ' ') > image-caching.tar
```

This should collect all the build layers of the given image and save them to a cache tar file.

Comment: Basically, for v1.10.0 and forward you cannot tag previous layers from an image's history unless the build cache is available.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by build-layer1 build-layer2 buld-layer3 here?  I don't have anything I can substitute.