# How to rollback in Amazon ECS with Amazon ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am stuck at with the rollback strategies on Amazon ECS using Amazon ECR as docker registry. I want to maintain the latest 5 image versions(say latestv1 latestv2 latestv3 latestv4 latestv5 etc) and Want to rollback to latestv4 if the code on latestv5 fails.

I have tried using amazon ecr cli and It gives me the all of the unsorted tags.

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name api-gateway-demo --output json --query imageDetails[*].imageTags
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "latestv2"
    ], 
    [
        "latestv1"
    ], 
    [
        "latestv5"
    ], 
    [
        "latestv3"
    ], 
    [
        "latestv4" 
    ]
]
```

Any idea to manage the versioning of the images for better deployment/rollbacks on ECR?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience the best scenario is to tag the image so you can rollback anytime from your registry private or not.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Also this might help you 
[Is there a way to tag a previous layer in a docker image or revert a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234611/is-there-a-way-to-tag-a-previous-layer-in-a-docker-image-or-revert-a-commit)

Comment: Yes, I have done it through the image versioning only. I have to write a script which manages the sorting part of the image.